# Как распарсить XML jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

Всем доброго!

На ajax запрос сервер мне отвечает xml следующего содержания:

код запроса:

```js
$.get(
  "https://адрес сервера",
  {
    "Param1": "0"
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

ответ сервера:

```html
<root>
  <Node1 EventDate="27.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node1>
  <Node2 EventDate="27.08.2017 16:00:00"></Node2>
  <Node3 EventDate="28.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node3>
  <Node4 EventDate="28.08.2017 16:00:00"></Node4>
  <Node5 EventDate="29.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node5>
  .......
 .......
 .......
  <Node34 EventDate="25.09.2017 8:00:00"></Node34>
</root>
```

Нужно просто собрать в массив содержимое EventDate:

```
["27.08.2017 8:00:00", "27.08.2017 16:00:00", "28.08.2017 8:00:00" ..... ]
```

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заворачиваем в `$`, а дальше работаем как с обычным HTML, осуществляя поиск всех элементов с атрибутом `EventDate` и извлекая данные из них:

```js
var response = '<root><Node1 EventDate="27.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node1><Node2 EventDate="27.08.2017 16:00:00"></Node2><Node3 EventDate="28.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node3><Node4 EventDate="28.08.2017 16:00:00"></Node4><Node5 EventDate="29.08.2017 8:00:00"></Node5><Node34 EventDate="25.09.2017 8:00:00"></Node34></root>';
var data = [];
$(response).find('[EventDate]').each(function() {
  data.push($(this).attr('EventDate'));
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!!